# Using JQuery or CSS how can I change the color of a box slowly on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, fadein

Using JQuery how can I change the color of a box slowly on hover?

I tried using the one below but how do i change the color of the box to red slowly on hover?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
         $(".box").hover(function(){
             $(".box").fadeIn("slow");
         },
         function(){
             $(".box").fadeOut();
         });
     }
     </script>
     <style>
         .box {
             background-color: #000;
         }

</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
         Box
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ or CSS3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS3:

```
.box {
-webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
-o-transition: all 800ms ease;
transition: all 800ms ease;

 }
 .box:hover {
-webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
-o-transition: all 800ms ease;
transition: all 800ms ease;
 }
```

Comment: This is easier than implementing JQuery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add jQuery UI  and animate the color like:

```
$(".box").hover(function () {
    $(".box").fadeIn("slow").animate({
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    });
}, function () {
    $(".box").fadeOut();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kvegJ/)**